# Go to definition in the base class

Tags: visual-studio, code-navigation

In Visual Studio when I have a base class with method
`public virtual void A()`
and a derived class with method
`public override void A()`
how can I navigate from the latter to the definition in the base class?

When I view the Call Hierarchy I see:
`A`
- Calls To '`A`'
- Calls To Base Member '`A`'
Not the definition Base `A`.

Answer (score 3):

In the method `public override void A()` set the cursor at the word `override` and press `F12` i.e. 'Go To Definition'.

It also works correctly when there are more levels of inheritance.

Comment: Not sure if this still works... In VS 2022 doing exactly that brings me to "xkeycheck.h", to the definition of the 'override' keyword.

Comment: It also works in Visual Studio Code (typescript)